# access control to JMX local monitoring

Tags: java, macos, jmx

I want to write an unprivileged (non-root-access) JMX client program that monitors a privileged (running as root) application that has JMX local access enabled  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote .

At least on MacOSX, jconsole (and jps) don't see root processes when I run as myself.

Is this just the fact of life here, or is there some way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is not permitted to see the root process, then you cannot attach by PID. What you need is to have the root application load a JMXServer that will listen on a [>1024] port and then you can connect through the port rather than by PID. The easiest way to do this would be to specify a couple of more system properties which will trigger the JVM to load a JMX server automatically. For example (these are all the most insecure):

- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
- -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7777

See [JMX Management and Monitoring Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html).

To create a JMXServer programmatically, see the JavaDoc for [javax.management.remote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/package-summary.html). There is a really good guide/tutorial on this topic [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).

Comment: Oh, please, please, can you point me to instructions for manually launching a JMX server instead of the -D stuff? And will such a server expose the build in VM beans?

Comment: Updating answer. And yes, this will allow you access to the built in VM MXBeans.

Answer (score 1):

JMX uses a simple TCP port that you can define with some command-line options. If the port is open, anyone (included non-priviledged users) should be able to see it.

As for the process itself, jps cannot see other user's process, but you can see then with "ps aux".