# JBoss JMX twiddle Runtime not registered

Tags: jboss, jmx

I have a problem with the `twiddle` script on a Solaris 10 server.
I have to read some properties e.g `jboss.system` and others.
All properties depending on the jboss server are fine, but when I try
to read properties from `java.lang`, the following error occurs:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: java.lang:type=Runtime is not registered.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that **java.lang:type=Runtime** is a *Platform MBeanServer* registered MBean and by default, twiddle connects you to the *JBoss MBeanServer* which by default, will not have the RuntimeMXBean server registered.

The easiest way to resolve this, assuming you only want to access system properties, is to point twiddle at the JBoss MBean [jboss:name=SystemProperties,type=Service](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/varia/property/SystemPropertiesService.html). The MBean exposes:

```
String get(String key)
String get(String key, String default)
```

or to retrieve all values,

```
Map shopwAll()
```

Other more laborious solutions would inlcude:

- Register the Platform MBeanServer MXBeans in the JBoss MBeanServer. See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784551/managed-mbeans-from-managementfactory-in-jdk1-6-notcompliantmbeanexception/5819736#comment-6795494).
- Enable the management agent in the JVM and use a JMX Connector to connect to the Platform MBeanServer. See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462236/access-control-to-jmx-local-monitoring/4464984#4464984).
- Use the [Attach API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html) to connect to the Platform MBeanServer of your JBoss Server by process ID. You can then reference the MXRuntime MBean.