# Jboss 6: Triggering GC via JMX

Tags: jboss, jmx

Is it possible to trigger GC via JMX in JBoss 6?
My problem is that the platform MBeans are not being published at all.
I enabled JMX with the jboss.platform.mbeanserver as follows:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9797,server=y,suspend=n"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8007"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.69.68.217"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.boot.server.log.dir=/app/logs/cps/log"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:/app/jboss6/boot/jboss-logmanager.jar"
```

A similar question was asked here.
[JBoss JMX twiddle Runtime not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175861/jboss-jmx-twiddle-question)

Many thanks,

Lee